# Python Threading Queue Twython

Tags: python, multithreading, twitter, queue

The aim of my code is to read the Tweet and light up a LED based on the term contained within the tweet. I tried using conventional coding method but for some reason it took forever to process the tweets.

Hence I am trying threading (which I am new to). The issue I am having is the tweets are read very well and instantly now but my code does not wait for the LED to turn off before processing the next tweet. So what I actually want to achieve is: Read Tweet --> Check if term in tweet --> light up LED --> Read next Tweet and so on. I am putting the tweets in queue and assigning workers to work on it. Below is part of my code.

```
class BlinkyLED(TwythonStreamer): 
    num_threads = 5
    check_string = ' '

    def on_success(self, data):
            global check_string
            if 'text' in data:
                    check_string = data['text'].encode('utf-8')
                    print 'Queuing:', check_string
                    q.put(check_string)

    def printTweet(i,q):
            while True:
                    print '%s: Waiting for the next Tweet' % i
                    check_string = q.get()
                    print '%s: Downloading:' % i, check_string
                    if TERM[0] in check_string:
                            print ' Turning ON Red LED'
                            GPIO.output(Red,GPIO.HIGH)
                            time.sleep(LED_secs_on)
                            print ' Turning OFF Red LED'
                            GPIO.output(Red,GPIO.LOW)

                    if TERM[1] in check_string:
                            print 'Turning ON Green LED'
                            GPIO.output(Green,GPIO.HIGH)
                            time.sleep(LED_secs_on)
                            print 'Turning OFF Green LED'
                            GPIO.output(Green,GPIO.LOW)

                    q.task_done()

    for i in range(num_threads):
            worker = Thread(target = printTweet, args = (i,q,))
            worker.setDaemon(True)
            worker.start()

    def on_error(self, status_code, data):
            print status_code
            self.disconnect()

    q.join()
    try:
        stream = BlinkyLED(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET,OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
        stream.statuses.filter(track=TERM)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Your code looks ok, although it is difficult just be reading... You are using only one thread I guess? And what is it you see? You see both traces `'Turning ON Green LED'` and `'Turning OFF Green LED'` but it goes too fast? You don't see the `OFF` trace?

Comment: Well in the code above I was using 5 threads but then changed it to 1 and it does seem to work fine as of now. When I use more than 1 thread it goes too fast as in it will read the first tweet, turn on the LED and then turn it off after lets say 5 seconds. It will queue the tweets received during those 5 seconds but it will process (turn on LED) for the tweet received right after 5 seconds (LED turned off).

Comment: Well, if you put more than one thread but all controlling the same LEDs you would have to add a mechanism to arbitrate between the LEDs (i.e. when one thread switches the LED on, the rest have to wait). But why do you need more than one thread anyway?

Comment: True that. I don't really need more than 1 thread. But what I noticed was when I search for a particular "@username" in the Tweet, it takes a long time to fetch. I can see the Queue sitting idle waiting for next Tweet. I tried using 2 threads but the same result.

Comment: Take into account that you are using the streaming [link](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/post/statuses/filter) thus you will have to wait until the @username you are following generates a message. Besides, since it is the Public API you only get a sample of tweets.

Comment: I found the error. The 'stream.statuses.filter(track=TERM)' should be replaced by 'stream.user()' . This will stream tweets tweeted only on the user's timeline and it happens instantly. I have tested with 10 tweets within a minute and it works perfectly fine. The tweets get queued and are processed one after the other without any delay.